# external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace); error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I'm doing a project for my college course with firebase and flutter. while signing up, it shows the error

> external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);

and shows

> Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
> error.

this is a screenshot of the debugging menu

[image: debugging menu screenshot]

user_model.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<UserModel> userModelFromJson(String str) =>
    List<UserModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => UserModel.fromJson(x)));

String userModelToJson(List<UserModel> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class UserModel {
  UserModel({
    this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.password,
    required this.category,
  });

  final String? id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final String password;
  final String category;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        name: json["name"],
        email: json["email"],
        phoneNumber: json["phone number"],
        password: json["password"],
        category: json["category"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "phone number": phoneNumber,
        "password": password,
        "category": category,
      };
}
```

user_repository.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:rentease/SignUp/Model/user_model.dart';

class UserRepository extends GetxController {
  static UserRepository get instance => Get.find();
  final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  createUser(UserModel user) async {
    try {
      await _db.collection("Users").add(user.toJson());
      Get.snackbar("Success", "Your Account has been created",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          colorText: Colors.white);
    } catch (error) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", "Something went wrong",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          colorText: Colors.white);
      // Return a value that is assignable to DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>
      return _db.collection("Users").doc();
    }
  }
}
```

i tried upgrading the **cloud_firestore** dependency to latest version, switching between multiple AVDs, tried with actual android device connected but still getting the same errors. i can still send data to firestore with these errors.

also tried this code before switching to **try** in **user_repository.dart**

```
createUser(UserModel user) async {
    await _db
        .collection("Users")
        .add(user.toJson())
        .whenComplete(
          () => Get.snackbar("Success", "Your Account has been created",
              snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              colorText: Colors.white),
        )
        .catchError((error) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", "Something went wrong",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          colorText: Colors.white);
    });
  }
```

Comment: `Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);` is not interesting.  That's a function that throws an exception.  You need to inspect the stack trace to determine what's calling that function and why.

Comment: @jamesdlin i've added a screenshot of the debugging menu in the post. can you check?

Comment: Your error message indicates that code attempted to use the null assertion operator (postfix `!`) on `null`.  Have you checked the referenced line number (`snackbar_controller.dart`, line 91) to see what caused that?  Work backwards from there.

Comment: @jamesdlin fixed it. just had to add GetMaterialApp instead of MaterialApp. thank you. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it. just had to add GetMaterialApp instead of MaterialApp

Answer (score 1):

i can help you

in pubscec.yaml, please do this:

assets:

```
- images/1.svg
```

you MUST write full name of your svg file

if you do this, you will have errore:

assets:

```
- images/
```

but when you write 1.svg after your asset folder, it will be OK